# Display a field from a content type which is not displayed in the current node

Tags: theming, nodes

I can add new variables to the node (like day, month, year) based on current node->created. The problem is I need to display the date field from another content type which is not displayed on the page. How do I fetch it from there?

Here is my code so far:

```
  function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
        $node = $vars['node'];
        $vars['year'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'Y' );
        $vars['month'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'm' );
        $vars['day'] = format_date($node->created, 'custom', 'd' );
      }
```

and I display them in node.tpl.php simply printing them as $day, $month, $year. I am interested in finding an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the node_load function.
Example:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  // Load node with ID 123.
  $another_node = $node_load(123);
  // Format a date.
  $vars['another_node_created'] = format_date($another_node->created, 'custom', 'Y, m, d' );
}
```

Beware that node_load returns raw data from the database. While `$another_node->created` is a safe value to use, user entered data (eg. the title or body text) needs to be checked before you print it (eg. `<?php print check_plain($another_node->title); ?>`). Not checking raw data is a security risk for your site. See [Handle text in a secure fashion](http://drupal.org/node/28984) for more info.